# REGEX (Tableau) return string between pipes `|` for every element separated by commas

Tags: regex, list, tableau-api

Heyo,
I am trying to extract either `level1` or `level2`, see example below, for every element from a string of elements in a list in Tableau.

> element1 | level1 | level2, element2 | level1 | level2

The "list" is a single dimension in Tableau. The hierarchy of each element in the list is separated by the pipe `|`, and the next element is separated by the comma `,`.

The expected output that I am thinking of would be:

> level1, level 1

OR:

> level2, level2

Based on the examples found searching stackoverflow, I have had varying success.

The following formula does return `element1`, but not `element2`. I need to be able to return all, and there are a varying number of "elements". I would also need to be able to specify which "level" that I wanted to return per formula.

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([list_o_elements], '^([^|]*)')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is "element1 | level1 | level2, element2 | level1 | level2" one row of data or is each row like "element1 | level1 | level2"?